# Market basket and clustering in Python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, market-basket-analysis

I have a large pandas `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
OrderID     OrderedItems    ItemsQuantity
10052009    I0                  2
10052009    I1                  1
10052009    I2                  1
10052009    I3                  1
10448900    I4                  5
10448900    I5                  5
10189322    I2                  1
10189322    I2                  1
```

Now, I want to find out what all items are ordered together and prevailing bundles.

Comment: Please follow a tutorial on frequent itemset mining.

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming you are aware of Clustering algorithms etc. You can use this data and with the  help of sklearn please run K Means on any other clustering Algo.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

PS: I am assuming your this is just sample of data.

Further similarly you can run Association algos.

Comment: You can't use kmeans on this data.